# LEFT JOIN 3 tables with group by and get sum

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have 3 tables t_customer, t_order and t_payment.

t_customer:

| customer_id | customer_name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | May |
| 2 | Jerry |

t_order:

| order_id | customer_id | order_amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 12.00 |
| 2 | 1 | 20.00 |
| 3 | 2 | 15.00 |

t_payment:

| payment_id | customer_id | pay_amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 15.00 |
| 2 | 1 | 12.00 |
| 3 | 2 | 12.00 |
| 4 | 2 | 3.00 |

**How to write the sql to get the following result?**

| customer_id | customer_name | SUM(order_amount) | SUM(pay_amount) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | May | 32.00 | 27.00 |
| 2 | Jerry | 15.00 | 15.00 |

I tried to left join these 3 tables, but I got the following result.

| customer_id | customer_name | order_amount | pay_amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | May | 12.00 | 15.00 |
| 1 | May | 12.00 | 12.00 |
| 1 | May | 20.00 | 15.00 |
| 1 | May | 20.00 | 12.00 |

As you can see, if I group the result by custom_id and sum order_amount and pay_amount, the result will be 64.00 & 54.00.

Here's my sql:

```sql
select tc.customer_id, custom_name, SUM(order_amount), SUM(pay_amount)
from t_customer tc
left join t_order t on tc.customer_id = t.customer_id
left join t_payment tp on tp.customer_id = tc.customer_id
group by tc.customer_id
```

Comment: can you share your query attempt at this problem?

Comment: @lemon I've updated the question and added my attempt at this problem.

Comment: Syntax error, no FROM clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue with your query is that when you combine `t_customer` with both `t_order` and `t_payment`, you get double combinations. Take a look at the output of this query to understand what I mean:

```
SELECT c.customer_id,
       c.customer_name,
       o.order_amount,
       p.pay_amount
FROM      t_customer c
INNER JOIN t_order o 
        ON c.customer_id = o.customer_id
INNER JOIN t_payment p 
        ON c.customer_id = p.customer_id
```

In order to avoid this issue, you can move the aggregation operations before the join operations:

```
SELECT c.customer_id,
       c.customer_name,
       COALESCE(o.total_order_amount, 0)   AS order_amount,
       COALESCE(p.total_pay_amount,   0)   AS pay_amount
FROM      t_customer c
LEFT JOIN (SELECT customer_id,
                  SUM(order_amount)  AS total_order_amount
           FROM t_order
           GROUP BY customer_id) o 
       ON c.customer_id = o.customer_id
LEFT JOIN (SELECT customer_id,
                  SUM(pay_amount)    AS total_pay_amount
           FROM t_payment
           GROUP BY customer_id) p 
       ON c.customer_id = p.customer_id
```

Check the demo [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/i9cn5JPZiiKTU91dVs2F8A/1).

Answer (score 1):

You could do a double join using a temporary table :

```
INSERT INTO t_final(customer_id,customer_name,order_amount) SELECT
    c.customer_id,
    c.customer_name,
    SUM(o.order_amount)
FROM      t_customer c
INNER JOIN t_order o ON c.customer_id = o.customer_id GROUP BY c.customer_id, c.customer_name;
UPDATE t_final SET pay_amount = (SELECT 
    SUM(p.pay_amount)
FROM t_payment p WHERE t_final.customer_id = p.customer_id GROUP BY t_final.customer_id LIMIT 1);
SELECT * FROM t_final;
```

Comment: Some customers may have an order but not have a payment, some customers have a payment before creating an order. So I can not use join in the query.

Comment: It should work with a RIGHT JOIN instead of a classic JOIN.